# Upload a file buffer using request promise to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, request

I'm using the request-promise library.  I'm trying to upload a file to a signed Amazon S3 URL:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var request = require('request-promise-native')
request({
  method: 'PUT',
  uri: 'https://MYBUCKET.amazonaws.com/myfile.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=KEY&Expires=1489006131&Signature=SIGNATURE',
  headers: {
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256',
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
  },
  file: fs.readFileSync('myfile.pdf')
}).then((r) => console.log('response', r)).catch((err) => console.log('err', err))
```

The request succeeds, but Amazon reports the file as 0 bytes in length.

Is the `file` parameter the correct argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want

```
body: fs.readFileSync('myfile.pdf')
```

instead of

```
file: fs.readFileSync('myfile.pdf')
```

Additionally, you can stream the file instead of buffering the entire file in memory first:

```
body: fs.createReadStream('myfile.pdf')
```

See the [`request` documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) for more information.

Comment: For me: `body: fs.createReadStream` did not work; `body: fs.readFileSync` did